# Change Zindex via xaml

Tags: .net, silverlight

Is it possible to update the zindex property of an element via a trigger in the xaml?

I thought something like below would work, but it's not:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
     <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Grid}"  PropertyName="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="999"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

thanks,
voss.

Comment: You have to add any XAML using the "code" button of the Stack Overflow text editor or it gets eaten (as unknown HTML elements).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to describe PropertyName as "(Canvas.ZIndex)" since ZIndex is attached property. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Denis...thansk for the feedback, but I don't really follow. What are you suggesting I change this line to?

Comment: PropertyName="(Canvas.ZIndex)" <- notice the parentheses. Altou I am not even sure that ChangePropertyAction can change attached property